# Index Error for pyplot contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, indexing, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to create a contour plot with matplotlib.pyplot using experimental data from a circuit. I am using the scipy curve_fit function with 3 parameters on the data (which is given by an array of size 251), but I keep getting an index error. Here is the part of my code for the plot:

```
Npts = 10000
v1scan = np.zeros(Npts) #voltage1
v2scan =np.zeros(Npts) #voltage2
tauscan = np.zeros(Npts) #time constant
chi_dof = np.zeros(Npts)
udata = np.zeros(Npts) #uncertainty
i = 0

dof = len(time) - len(popt)

for v1par in np.linspace(0, 8, 100, True):
    for v2par in np.linspace(0, 8, 100, True): 
        for taupar in np.linspace(5*(10**-5), 7*(10**-5), 100, True):
            v1scan[i] = v1par
            v2scan[i] = v2par
            tauscan[i] = taupar
            dymin = (vcap - capvoltage(time, v1par, v2par, taupar))/(0.02*vcap) #vectorized
            chi_dof[i] = sum(dymin*dymin)/dof
            i = i + 1
plt.figure() #creates new figure
ncols = 10
plt.tricontourf(v1par, v2par, taupar, chi_dof, ncols)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The error message I get is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-175-7562791ba165> in <module>()
     12     for v2par in np.linspace(0, 8, 100, True):
     13         for taupar in np.linspace(5*(10**-5), 7*(10**-5), 100, True):
---> 14             v1scan[i] = v1par
     15             v2scan[i] = v2par
     16             tauscan[i] = taupar

IndexError: index 10000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10000
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

100 times 100 times 100 = 1000000 and not 10000

As soon as i reaches 10000 (where its max value should be 9999) you try to access an out of memory region.

EDIT: fix:

```
Npts = 1000000
```

Comment: That did make the error message go away (thank you). Although now the plot simply won't show (no error message, just nothing is happening).

Comment: Well, that is a different problem. Does a simple plot work? `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` `plt.plot([1, 2, 3])` `plt.show()` (all in a file)